# Specify an image to be used in a CSS class' background property

Tags: html, css

I'd like to have a CSS class that lets me specify an image and use it as a background. The image has several filters applied to it. I can get it to work if the image is hardcoded into the CSS, but I don't want to duplicate this style for each possible image across my website. How can I specify in HTML what the image should be?

```
.short-block {
   background: linear-gradient(#FFFFFF00 50%,#0A0F31BF 100%), 
               linear-gradient(#00204499,#19274C99), 
               linear-gradient(#002868BF,#002868BF), 
               url('../images/block_backgrounds/congress.png'); /* I want to specify this in HTML */
   background-blend-mode: darken, normal;
   background-size: cover;
}
```

[image: Starting with any image:]

[image: I apply a handful of gradients to get a shaded version:]

Answer (score 0):

Cleanest way I've come up with is to use inline styling to override a variable:

HTML:

```
<div class="imageblock" style="--bgImage: url('../images/block_backgrounds/liberty.jpg');">
    Proudly Made In America
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.imageblock {
   --bgImage: url('../images/block_backgrounds/congress.jpg');
   background: linear-gradient(#00286800 70%,#002868FF 100%), 
               linear-gradient(#00204499,#19274C99), 
               linear-gradient(#002868BF,#002868BF), 
               var(--bgImage);
   background-blend-mode: normal, darken, normal;
   background-size: cover;
   background-position: center; 
}
```